# how to add salary in every row of a table

Tags: sql-server

I have a table Employee in sql server.Suppose Employee table has three Column Id,Name and salary.and there are 10 rows inserted in table.
                                               So I want to write a query for adding 500 Rs in each employee salary.Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the salary is stored as "Rs" (presumably Rupee if you're from India):

```
update Employee set salary = salary + 500
```

This will do what you request, adding 500 to each salary attribute in every row. You can add a `where` clause if you want to limit the rows which get affected but that doesn't appear to be in your requirements.

Comment: Thanks,but i want do it this task by loop through cursor.can u please provide me the query through cursor and loop.(e.g use of FETCH_Next)

Comment: @coolhimanshu, no, because what you're considering is actually a bad idea :-) You should leave this work up to the database as much as possible rather than inefficiently running a cursor and doing it piecemeal. If you want to change all rows, use the query I gave. If you want to select specific rows, do that with a where clause.

Answer (score 0):

```
update employee set salary = salary+500
```

Answer (score 0):

It will work

```
Update employee set salary=salary+500
```